# Mass Luminosity Relation Review

Tags: mass, astrophysics, stars, stellar-physics, luminosity

I have read that exists a relation between the luminosity and the mass of a star

$$\frac{L}{L_\odot}=\left(\frac{M}{M_\odot}\right)^a$$

with $a$ depending on the mass $M$. I have looked for a review about the argument explaining the application of such a treatment, but I found nothing which satisfied my questions. Can you suggest me a reference?

These are my questions:

1. How strong this relation? It is only empirical or it follows also from theoretical arguments?
2. What are the stars compatible with this relation? Main Sequence stars? Cepheids?

Comment: Have you seen [the Wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93luminosity_relation)? Can you explain what you are looking for that isn't covered by that article?

Answer (score 1):

The mass-luminosity relationship is widely used while dealing with stellar astrophysics. I will answer your questions in the reverse order:-

Stars of different masses adhere to the M-L relationship by adopting different values of the constant a. Here is a rough idea from [Advanced Astrophysics](https://books.google.com/books?id=-ljdYMmI0EIC&lpg=PA19&ots=VdMUIiCdP_&dq=Mass-luminosity%20relation&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false)

$$ \frac{L}{L_{\odot}} \sim 0.23\left(\frac{M}{M_\odot}\right)^{2.3} \textit{ for } \left(M < 0.43\,M_\odot\right)$$

$$ \frac{L}{L_{\odot}} \sim \left(\frac{M}{M_\odot}\right)^{4} \textit{ for } \left(M > 0.43\,M_\odot\right)$$

Note that different literature sources will give you slightly different values of a and the mass range. For eg. some people like to use a = 3.5 for   $\,\,2\,M_\odot<M<20\,M_\odot$. This is because (now coming to your second question) this law is empirical and is usually only applied to main sequence stars. Although you can hypothetically come up with such a law for other types of stars by doing enough observations.

However, note that it is possible to prove using basic physics the basic relation between mass and luminosity that was derived by Arthur Eddington $\,L\propto M^3$ [ See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93luminosity_relation#cite_note-advanced-4) for a basic proof]